# How is it true that if $||v||_2=1$ then we can always find a vector $w$ satisfying $w^{*}v=1$ with $||w||_2=1$?

Tags: normed-spaces

How is it true that if $||v||_2=1$ then we can always find a vector $w$ satisfying $w^{*}v=1$ with $||w||_2=1$ ?  I am seeing my instructor write that on the board as if we should know how to prove that, but I am missing its understanding it!!

Here is an example of where it appears: https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/pseudospectra/thms/thm1.pdf  Look halfway into the proof for the first theorem.

I am not able to understand why this is the case.  Can someone help me understand this please ?

Comment: How about $w=v$? Is $||\cdot||$ the norm corresponding to the standard inner product?

Comment: it's the 2 norm.

Comment: @guimption No, the notes you linked to do not assume it's the 2-norm.

Comment: As stated in the following sentence of the proof you are referencing, it is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem (see third bullet [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Important_consequences)).

Comment: As cited in the pdf, see the proof of  Theorem 4.2, https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/linear-stability-analysis-in-the-numerical-solution-of-initial-value-problems/AF482B56235DB71170EEBF7739D50A93. Apparently $w^*v$ in the pdf denotes the natural paring of a vector $v$, and $w$ an element from the dual. $\|\cdot\|$ in the note is not necessarily the 2-norm.

Comment: So, you are referring to "In particular, if V is a normed vector space and if z is any element ..." @angryavian ?  Sorry...having trouble following that logic still.  am I not understanding something big here?

Comment: The key question seems to me to be how $w^\ast v$ is defined.  How is it, or just $w^\ast$ for that matter, defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the file that you linked, this is a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

There are many forms of the Hahn-Banach theorem; the Wikipedia page states it in much generality, and specializes to the case of normed vector spaces only in passing (under the section "Important consequences"). A statement of Hahn-Banach for normed vector spaces can be found [here (Theorem 1)](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/245b-notes-6-duality-and-the-hahn-banach-theorem/), reproduced here:

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space, and let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Then any continuous linear functional $f$ on $Y$ can be extended to a linear functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ with the same operator norm; thus $\tilde{f}$ agrees with ${f}$ on $Y$ and $\|\tilde{f}\| = \|f\|$.

Let us apply this form of the theorem to your question. $Y:=\text{span}\{v\}$ is a subspace of your vector space, whose elements are of the form $cv$ for scalars $c$. You can check that $f(cv)=c\|v\|$ is a linear functional on this subspace $Y$ that has norm $\|f\|=1$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, this functional can be extended to a functional $\tilde{f}$ on your entire vector space such that $\tilde{f}=f$ on $Y$, and $\|\tilde{f}\|=1$. In your situation you are in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (more generally, the following is true whenever the Riesz representation theorem applies), so there exists some vector $w$ such that this linear functional $\tilde{f}$ can be written as $\tilde{f}(x) = w^* x$. Transferring the properties of $\tilde{f}$, we have $w^*v =\tilde{f}(v) = f(v) = \|v\|$ and $\|w\| = \|\tilde{f}\|=1$.

Comment: $f(x) = \Vert x \Vert$ is not linear; for example, $f(-x) = \Vert -x \Vert = \Vert x \Vert = f(x)$, but linearity either over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ demands $f(-x) = -f(x) \ne f(x)$ for $f(x) \ne 0$

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks for catching my mistake; I've corrected it.